# Better LIC health insurance plan? [India]

Tags: insurance, healthcare, india

I have just started working. I have a plan of taking a insurance for myself
where I could pay a maximum of Rs.2000 as premium.

Can any one suggest how I should go about finding a better policy for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.healthinsuranceindia.org/default.asp) could be a starting point. The author is a knowledgable person and the best part is he isn't trying to sell his stuff. But this shouldn't be your only option.

[Use this to compare insurance from different providers](http://www.itrust.in/life-insurance.action).

Also read the fine print while taking a policy. Many of the subtler points might bite you later. So be aware of what to expect and what not to after you take your policy. Premium shouldn't be the deciding factor of your policy. But what would be the maximum coverage you can get for the premium you pay, should be your target.